# Is it possible to allow a text in a table to overflow outside of its cell?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a bit of a weird situation where I'm trying to build a legal template and getting completely frustrated by how finnicky tables in Word are. Here's what I'm working with:

[image]

Ultimately it will look like this:
[image]

Ideally I want the 'Title' content control box to be able to show "in front of" the table. Right now it's being hidden by the cell right below it. I've tried multiple ways to fix this issue. I first merged the two cells into one, but then the problem is that the text becomes misaligned, and either shows up too far to the top or the bottom of the cell. And I can't seem to make single cell adjustments without also somehow affecting the left row. I was hoping that I could just select the 'Title' content control box and "bring to front" but that option is greyed out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the cells that contain this with one or more of the cells below it.

Because I want to emphasize the title, I actually put it in a column-spanning row that uses the Title Document Property Content Control (under Quick Parts).

With gridlines:

[image: Screenshot with gridlines]

Without gridlines:

[image: screenshot without gridlines]

*Both are still showing the content control bounding box/tag, bookmarks, and table selection box.*

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've definitely tried this approach but still ran into some problems. (Red line added by me) 

Here's what it looks like when I merge the two cells:
https://imgur.com/cGui2Xz


For whatever reason, the two text boxes end up being slightly misaligned. This was originally my solution until I kept noticing it.


Here's what it looks like when I tell the merged cell to align to the top: https://imgur.com/OLY3hH1


And here's what happens when I try to add a cell margin to only the merged cell:
https://imgur.com/MSA0HCZ

Comment: This looks like you may have Track Changes turned on.

Comment: I don't. The red line you see was added by me in Paint to show the misalignment. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to.